# How to see which graphics card is loaded on start or install

Tags: drivers, ati, freeze, hp

I have a brand new [HP Desktop PC](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02754767&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=5035344&prodTypeId=12454) (Pavilion Elite HPE-557de).

I have tried to install some versions of Ubuntu (10.10, 11.04, 11.10 Beta 2) for 2 days, and every time GNOME is started, after 2-3 minutes of work Ubuntu freezes. After a hard restart it comes the same problem.

I gave the PC to one PC expert, who has installed 5 different Linux distributions and also is coming the same problem. Every time Linux is started, then it freezes.

My question is, is it possible that the on-board graphics card is not disabled, and it is doing this freezing stuff? HP says that "Integrated video is not available if a graphics card is installed", but is there a possibility, that this is not the case?

How can I see which card is loaded?

Comment: What graphics card does your system use? It sounds to me like you are getting a problem that usually occurs when Kernel mode setting is enabled with some open source drivers.

Comment: It is an AMD Radeon HD 6850 ... like in the description of the PC, when you click on the link.

Comment: it's better if you mention that directly in your question. We cannot be sure that you kept the same graphics card that came with the system, unless we are God himself.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

What does your /etc/X11/xorg.congf look like and what does this produce:

```
fglrxinfo
```

If you haven't added the additional proprietary driver for your card, its easy to check by running the following commands in terminal

sudo su
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

the fglrx proprietary driver takes this away. so if you install a fresh system etc, see the output. It gives an output like-

0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0

1:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0

IGD = integrated graphics, DIS = discrete graphics, on an HP it might show both as powered, and the '+' sign will show which one is in use.